# Handling a many to many relationship in sql

Tags: sql, many-to-many, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two main tables. CARS and FEATURES. A car have many features and a feature can have many cars. Therefore a bridge table sits in between them called CARFEATURE. It has the PKFKCarID and PKFKFeature ID. I want to query cars that only have the specific features I assign. How would I do this with SQL.

I've tried, SELECT * FROM CARFEATURE WHERE FEADTUREID = 'GPS' AND FEATUREID = 'RADIO'. BUT i end up getting null result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various options.  I'd guess that you want

```
select carID
  from carFeature
 where featureID in ('GPS', 'Radio')
 group by carID
having count(distinct featureID) = 2
```

You could also do

```
select carID
  from carFeature
 where featureID = 'GPS'
intersect
select carID
  from carFeature
 where featureID = 'Radio'
```

The latter query is a bit clearer in my opinion but it's probably not as efficient as the first.

Comment: Thank You So Much. I finally got my query to work the way I wanted it to.